# Decision tree vs Decision space

Tags: algorithm, data-mining, decision-tree

I understand given tabular data how to create a decision tree from scratch. I program in python, we create a class called node inside the class we can add functions making child, root, split etc.
May be videos like this explain the process.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgQAhG5Q7iY&ab_channel=NormalizedNerd

I want to write a class for decision space. That represents the data points in the tabular data in a plane or higher dimension space. Then create a partition based on the decision tree.
So let say we have the decision tree. given in the following picture. The data set has two features age and degree. At the age =4 there is split and then degree has a split at at degree =2. So I want to define a class that return me right hand side in the picture.

Decision space is more general than decision tree. So is there is an implementation in python from scratch ? So I am guessing we convert a decision tree to rule set and then from rule set we can from rule space?

Definition 1. A decision space is an m-dimensional (product) space $Dattr_1$ × · · · × Dattr_i × · · · × Dattr_m where m is the
number of attributes and Dattr_i is the space covered by the i-th attribute specified as a bounded poset (i.e., a partially
ordered set with a least and the greatest element).

[image]

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. First you say you want to implement it "from scratch", but then you say "is there an implementation in python?". Those are the opposite of each-other - either you implement it yourself from scratch or you use an existing implementation.

Comment: Anyway, there is a convenient implementation of decision trees in library scikit-learn, and you can plot a 2d decision space with graphviz. See [this tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) for an example.

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear, but I wanted to create a class for decision space. Decision spaces are more general than a decision tree. Not all decision space can be a decision tree.

Comment: Hence given a dataset where we assume each feature is partially ordered and that have a lower bound and upper bound. We can create a class decision space.

Comment: Again, I can't see what your actual question is here.  1) *"So is there is an implementation in python from scratch?"* - Off-topic!  2) *"So I am guessing we convert a decision tree to rule set and then from rule set we can from rule space?"*  - Sounds like a reasonable guess.  But I'm not sure how that relates to the rest of the (erm) question.

Comment: It strikes me that what you really need to do is some more research to make sure that you understand what you want your (proposed) decision space class to do; e.g. in the context of the algorithms you will be using.  Then just design and implement it.  Be prepared to iterate on your design; e.g. expect to make mistakes and correct them.  I don't think we can advise you on what the design should look like.